# Porting algorithm from Python to Go

Tags: go

I am trying to port this python code to Go but there is no **beta()** in math package. Where can i find beta and other functions required for this?

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.stats import beta


class BetaBandit(object):
    def __init__(self, num_options=2, prior=(1.0,1.0)):
        self.trials = zeros(shape=(num_options,), dtype=int)
        self.successes = zeros(shape=(num_options,), dtype=int)
        self.num_options = num_options
        self.prior = prior

    def add_result(self, trial_id, success):
        self.trials[trial_id] = self.trials[trial_id] + 1
        if (success):
            self.successes[trial_id] = self.successes[trial_id] + 1

    def get_recommendation(self):
        sampled_theta = []
        for i in range(self.num_options):
            #Construct beta distribution for posterior
            dist = beta(self.prior[0]+self.successes[i],
                        self.prior[1]+self.trials[i]-self.successes[i])
            #Draw sample from beta distribution
            sampled_theta += [ dist.rvs() ]
        # Return the index of the sample with the largest value
        return sampled_theta.index( max(sampled_theta) )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about [`numpy.random.beta`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.beta.html), the Beta distribution which is a special case of the Dirichlet distribution, and is related to the Gamma distribution, you can check the project [**`gostat`**](https://code.google.com/p/gostat/).

It has a [`beta.go` source code](https://code.google.com/p/gostat/source/browse/stat/beta.go) which implements that function.